# PHP function's return value to html tag

Tags: php, html

My Class.php content:

```
<?php
class Class
{
    public function validate()
    {
        if(empty($_POST['first_name']))
        {
            return 'first name is required!';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['middle_name']))
        {
            return 'middle name is required!';
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['last_name']))
        {
            return 'last name is required'
        }
        else {
            return 'success!';
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my html file, I want to display the return values of my function validate to a different html ID at the same time.

```
<?php
require 'Class.php';
$class = new Class();
$class->validate()
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOME FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <span id="first_empty"></span> <!-- Return first name is required! -->

        <input type="text" name="middle_name">
        <span id="middle_empty"></span> <!-- Return middle name is required! -->

        <input type="text" name="last_name">
        <span id="last_empty"></span> <!-- Return last name is required! -->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display all 3 returns at the same time. thanks

Comment: what do you mean by a different html id? What is your desired result?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but you would have to tell your validation method what you are on at the moment: `$class->validate('first_name')`, then your validation would check if that post key/value is empty and return the proper message.

Comment: different ID for a specific field like, id_name, id_address and my desired result is that to display them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your function a bit.

So far, you're returning validation messages one by one. If you want to return all error messages together, you should create an array.

Follow this approach:

Your function contains two variables:

$errors     Array  Storing all error messages

$response   Array

"message" -> Appropriate message explanation current state.

"errors"  -> Contains list of errors. It's null if there are no errors.

```
 public function validate()
 {
    $response = array();
    $errors   = array();

    if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {

        $errors['first_name'] = 'first name is required!';

    } elseif(empty($_POST['middle_name'])) {

        $errors['middle_name'] = 'middle name is required!';

    } elseif(empty($_POST['last_name'])) {

        $errors['last_name'] = 'last name is required'
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $response['message'] = 'Success';
        $response['errors']  = null;
    } else {
         $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong';
         $response['errors']  = $errors;
    }
}
```

And then, call the function and check for errors:

```
<?php
  require 'Class.php';
  $class = new Class();
  $response = $class->validate();

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($response); // Check response
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        <?php
    class Class_demo
    {
        public function validate()
        {
            $err = array();
            if(empty($_POST['first_name']))
            {
                $err['first_name'] = 'first name is required!';
            }
            if(empty($_POST['middle_name']))
            {
                $err['middle_name'] = 'middle name is required!';
            }
            if(empty($_POST['last_name']))
            {
                $err['last_name'] = 'last name is required';
            }

            if(!empty($err))
            {
                return $err;
            }   
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
    {   
        $class = new Class_demo();
        $response_msg = $class->validate();
        echo "<pre>";
        if(!empty($response_msg['first_name']))
        {   
            print_r($response_msg['first_name'] ."<br/>");
        }
        if(!empty($response_msg['middle_name']))
        {
            print_r( $response_msg['middle_name'] ."<br/>");
        }   
        if(!empty($response_msg['last_name']))
        {
            print_r($response_msg['last_name']);
        }   
        if(empty($response_msg)) 
        {
            print_r('Success'); 
        }               

    }   
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>SOME FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
            <span id="first_empty"></span> <!-- Return first name is required! -->

            <input type="text" name="middle_name">
            <span id="middle_empty"></span> <!-- Return middle name is required! -->

            <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <span id="last_empty"></span> <!-- Return last name is required! -->

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_form">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```